# Windows 10 completely non-functional, even after fresh install. Could it be hardware-related?

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure

As the title states, I've been having a particularly odd set of problems with my PC lately. It began approximately 2 weeks ago, with random and infrequent BSODs (usually "CRITICAL PROCESS FAILED" errors). Then, I noticed that any new files I downloaded from the internet or programs I installed would be completely gone after rebooting the system: it's as if my computer kept reverting to an earlier state without saying anything every time it got rebooted. Then, it progressed to the point that the computer was literally unusable: programs would not open (error message would pop up saying said program isn't compatible with my version of Windows), it would stutter horrifically, and it would BSOD after a few minutes. Finally, it had a crash I have never seen and it was not able to recover from: quick flash of a BSOD, followed by an unresponsive black screen with a blinking cursor in the upper left corner (like a command line interface).

My specs are as follows:

```
OS          - Windows 10 Pro
CPU         - Ryzen 5 3600
Motherboard - Gigabyte Aorus B450 Pro WiFi (rev. 1.0), UEFI version F50
Video Card  - MSI Mech OC RX 5700XT
Memory      - Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro DDR4-3200 non-buffered non-EEC, 2x16GB
C Drive     - TCSunbow 480GB SSD
D Drive     - Sandisk Ultra 512GB SSD
```

Things I have tried:

- Swapping RAM DIMMs to other pair of slots
- Swapping in known good RAM
- Reinstalling previous CPU (Ryzen 3 2200G)
- Reinstalling previous video card (RX 570)
- Disconnecting D Drive
- Switching SATA jack C Drive is connected to
- Disconnecting power supply and removing CMOS battery for 15 minutes
- Replacing CMOS battery
- Reflashing UEFI
- Doing a total fresh reinstall of Windows on the C drive

The fresh reinstall (using USB boot device created using Microsoft's tool on another computer) worked, kinda. The install process goes completely smoothly, and I can get in and actually use Windows for about 2 minutes. It defaults to a resolution of 1024x768, and changing it to 1920x1080 (my monitor's resolution) or anything else will cause the computer to freeze – after ~2 minutes, it will switch the resolution on its own and freeze. I will hear the system sound that plays when you disconnect something repeat every 5-10 seconds, and the screen will just show the desktop (no mouse cursor, either). After a short period, the screen will go black and the sound will continue to repeat. If I hard restart, I get the Windows logo for a few seconds until it cuts to a black screen (no sound this time).

I've searched for days but I cannot find a fix. Is it the SSD I'm using for my C drive bad? Is my motherboard bad? Power supply? I just don't know at this point.

Comment: Run for a while from a Live USB operating system, such as Linux. If everything appears normal, then likely it is the SSD at fault, since the system works when the SSD is not in use.

Comment: First open command prompt and scan your system for issues using `sfc /scannow`. If it does not fix then try using dism: `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`. Update device drivers and uninstall any recent windows 10 updates.

Comment: You should try to disconnect the C drive and install Windows on another SSD (the D drive perhaps) or HDD drive. If problems persist then it is very likely that the motherboard needs to be replaced. Otherwise the hardware to replace is the 480 GB SSD

Comment: Even without the hindsight that it was the SSD, "TCSunbow" sticks out to me as a dodgy brand. Recommend you stick with known brands for storage, and even then keep backups to avoid data loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help! Narrowed it to the SSD rather than the motherboard. Installed a new SSD and I'm back up and running. Thanks, all!